# Microsoft Graph client throw exception ErrorApiQuarantined when get photo

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API version 1.9.0 and I was able to get my photo by this code

```
        try
        {
            var originalPhoto = await GraphClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
            return originalPhoto;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

But from today it throws exception:

*Code: ErrorApiQuarantined
Message: Request has been quarantined by condition.*

This is the response header

```
request-id: 4189c59d-9c1f-4686-945d-2cb9756491ed
client-request-id: 4189c59d-9c1f-4686-945d-2cb9756491ed
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East Asia","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_1"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: private
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 03:20:09 GMT
```

Please let me know what is happening with my Graph Client.

Comment: Can you paste request id of the failure here and Ill notify product owner?

Comment: @IvanFranjic The request Id is 4189c59d-9c1f-4686-945d-2cb9756491ed

Comment: It is blocked due to excessive queries. I requested unblock, will let you know once unblocked.

Comment: Thanks @IvanFranjic. I have researched documentation related to this issue but I haven't found it. Can you let me know where I can find my threshold? My application is a multi tenant app and it is required to query to graph service in high frequency.

Comment: It seems that your application started to generate huge amount of extended properties against mailboxes and that is the reason for quarantine. Can you validate what are and why those properties are generated?

Answer (score 1):

This is not client side issue. Requests on the servers are blocked  for specific api/tenant/user due to excessive usage which can degrade service. I suggest you file case with support to check with product group what condition led to this and why rule is created. Usually these rules are created temporarily.